# Postman GET returning HTML and status 200

Tags: spring-boot, postman-testcase

I am trying to call a Postman GET endpoint, and it is returning HTML and status 200, instead of a valid JSON response and status 200. It looks like it is not hitting the backend at all. I have a separate POST endpoint, which works fine and returns me a valid JSON response.

Could this be due to authorization headers? I am using the same authorization for both.

[image]

Comment: Without seeing URL and code for the back-end, it is a bit difficult. My guess is that you are using wrong mime-type somewhere

Comment: I managed to resolve it. I had to add a cookie header, which I got from the browser since I was able to call the service from the browser and I had authenticated on browser level.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue.  I had to add a cookie header, which I got from the browser since I was able to call the service from the browser and I had authenticated on browser level.

[image]